# Database list data onClick

Tags: android, database

i have a list with some data from my database.I would like to have a dialog when the user clicks every item of the list.The dialogs will have the same layout between them but different text,taken from the database.My problem is that with my code i m getting dialogs with the same content..This is my onClick code

```
HotOrNot entry=new HotOrNot(this);
                        entry.open();
                Cursor cursor = entry.getData();
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.agonessingle);
                dialog.setCancelable(true);         

                 String description2 = DBHelper.DESCRIPTION;
                    String skord2 = DBHelper.SKOR;
                    String goala2 = DBHelper.GOALA;
                    String goalb2 = DBHelper.GOALB;
                    String title2 = DBHelper.TITLE;
                        TextView firsttext = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.firstdialog);
                         firsttext.setText(title2);

                          TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
                          text.setText(description2);
                          TextView text2 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView2);
                          text2.setText(skord2);
                          TextView text3 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView3);
                          text3.setText(goala2);
                          TextView text4 = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.TextView4);
                          text4.setText(goalb2);

                          entry.close();
                      dialog.show();
```

Will it be better to use a CustomAdapter for this job?Please help,i have stacked here for days!

Answer (score 0):

have a list with some data from my database.I would like to have a dialog when the user clicks every item of the list.The dialogs will have the same layout between them but different text,taken from the database.My problem is that with my code i m getting dialogs with the same content..This is my onClick code

If You are using the onClick, when the user will clicks you have to update the Dialog contants i.e string object and reset the dialog.

Comment: can you give me an example on that please?